# Finding a distinction which row is from which cursor?

Tags: mergecursor

I have used `MergeCursor` in my code, two loaders give two cursors. First one loads all audios from `External_Content_Uri` and Second one from `Internal_Content_Uri`.

The Problem is when I merge both these cursors and populate a List with audios, and I intend to play them through mediaplayer. To set the `DataSource`, I must find a way to know which song was from the external storage and which one was from internal storage.

While I'm populating the List from `mergedcursor`, is there a way to know whether the current row from cursor is the one from `External_Content_Uri` or `Internal_Content_Uri`?

And is it possible to add an additional column to these cursors returned by the loaders in `OnLoadFinished()`?